# Object Collection to List<> doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have this code for casting `CheckedListBox.Items` to `List<Item>`:

```
List<Item> items = ChkLsBxItemsToDraw.Items as List<Item>;
```

and this is my `Item` Class

```
public class Item
{
    public List<double> x = new List<double>();
    public List<double> y = new List<double>();
}
```

I set `CheckedListBox.DataSource` to a `List<Item>`

and I got this Error:

> Error 1   Cannot convert type '`System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Drower.Item>`' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

How Can I get the `CheckedListBox.Items` as `List<Item>` ???

Comment: What is going wrong? What is the error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k86hzt9t.aspx) and the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items.aspx) properties are unrelated. The fact that you set the first property doesn't mean that you will get anything in the second. For example if you check the number of items it will be 0: `ChkLsBxItemsToDraw.Items.Count`.

You could add elements to the Items property:

```
List<Item> items = ...
ChkLsBxItemsToDraw.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

and later retrieve them back as a list:

```
List<Item> items = ChkLsBxItemsToDrawItems.Cast<Item>().ToList();
```

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee, you could add elements to the `Items` property using the `.Add` method: `ChkLsBxItemsToDraw.Items.Add(someItem)` or a range of items using the `.AddRange` method.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee It depends on what you want in a higher-level perspective. Try explaining you use case, rather than your code issue. What do you want your program do? Update your question.

Answer (score 7):

```
List<Item> items = this.ChkLsBxItemsToDraw.Items.Cast<Item>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Item
{
    public List<double> x = new List<double>();
    public List<double> y = new List<double>();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CheckedListBox box = new CheckedListBox();
    box.Items.OfType<Item>().ToList();
}
```